# img.onload url only works with certain external src URLs

Tags: image, url, external, onload, src

I am using the following code to grab an image from URL and convert it into Base64:

```
  function convertImgToBase64(url, callback){
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        img = new Image;
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        callback.call(this, dataURL);
        canvas = null;
    };
    img.src = url;
  }

  convertImgToBase64(INSER_URL_HERE, function(base64Img){
    $("#data_url").text(base64Img);
    imageRef.set(base64Img);
  });
```

I am thoroughly confused. So far, the code works and img.onload is fired ONLY when I have tested it using images from Wikipedia (e.g. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png)! All other external image URLs I have tried do not fire img.onload (e.g. http://www.ipadenclosures.com/php-oak/themes/global/admin_images/Apple_gray_logo.png). Any ideas why these images are not loading?